# how to set default value as Guid when field is blank at the time of deserializing

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to pull records from server via webservice in and in my model I have a parameter named `public String mId {get;set;}` and my JSON structure is as follows

```
{  "name":"Jhon",  "mId":"",  "address":"55 jump street" }
```

Now when `mId` is blank i want to generate a new `GUID` for this field while deserializing json using `Newton JSON` as `[DefaultValue("")]` is accepting only constant value i can not use `Guid.NewGuid()` over there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not what `DefaultValue` is used for. To add a default value:

```
string mId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid()
```